# Moving fields to another table and using that id to update rows in a third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables called "itemorders", "mycart" and "products". I am currently moving the items in mycart into itemorders table like this in my multiquery.

```
$query = "INSERT into itemorders 
  (itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemColour,itemPrice,quantity,orderID) 
   SELECT itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemColour,itemPrice,quantity, 
 LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM mycart WHERE email='".$email."'  ";
```

How do I use the itemID,itemColour and quantity from my query and use them to update the quantity field in the products table?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `UPDATE INNER JOIN` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) if your `itemorders` table also has a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Something like:

```
UPDATE products p
INNER JOIN itemorders i ON p.itemID = i.itemID AND p.itemColour = i.itemColour
SET p.quantity = p.quantity - i.quantity
WHERE i.ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

I haven't tested this and ensuring you handle the business invariants around avoiding going into negative stock counts is left as an exercise for the reader.

> P.S. Also be careful about SQL injection attacks (the way you are interpolating the email may make life harder for poor Bobby Tables. https://xkcd.com/327/), I'd recommend looking into PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php.

Comment: Hi does this work on multiple rows? Lets say  i was inserting 2 unique rows in the first query will it update the 2 unique products?